# customer's password not displayed in email templates magento 2.1.5

Tags: email-templates, customer-account, transactional-mail, magento2.1.5

I have try to add password on customer account email template but not able to getting password. Any one knows how can i set password on customer email template ?

Really appreciate who knows solution.

Answer (score 0):

For **security purpose,** magento  have stop sending customer password to email.

This happen bcoz of make ***customer details  more confidential***.
There are some tricky way  you can do that but it lot of work need